# How to fit 4 columns in 3 column HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

I don't know how to word this question but I'm working on a table and it has 3 columns everywhere but I want to fit 4 cells in into one row so that the width remains the same. How do I do it?
This is what I mean:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
| 1|2 |3|4|
-------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? The outer columns are 33% width so it fits the width of the screen. The inner columns of the table is set to 25% width so it fits within the 33% columns. I have given each column a different color border so you can see how it looks.

```css
.column1, .column2, .column3{width:33.3%; font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";padding:5px 0px;}
 .column1{border:1px solid #ff0000;}
 .column2{border:1px solid #fff000;}
 .column3{border:1px solid #000000;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">1</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
      <td class="column2"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">1</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
      <td class="column3"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">1</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">2</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">3</td>
            <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

try this using nested tables

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="200">
 <tr>
     <td>
         <table width="100%"  border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
                 <td width="33%" align="center">1</td>
                    <td width="33%" align="center">2</td>
                    <td width="33%" align="center">3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
         <table width="100%"  border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
                 <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td align="center">2</td>
                    <td align="center">3</td>
                    <td align="center">4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```